# Solving a linear matrix equation non-numerically

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Is there any way to solve for $V$ when other matrices in the below equation are known?
$V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and is symmetrical, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times (n-1)}$, and $V_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times (n-1)}$ is a partition of $V$ without the first row and column.
$$V  - BV_{0}B^T=X$$

I've solved it numerically using R (where $V$ is eigendecomposed to ensure it is symmertical) but I wonder if there is a quicker way. Here's the function to be minimised for solving this equation,

```
h<-function(U,X,B){
p<-nrow(X)
U<-matrix(U,nrow=p,ncol=p)
V<-U%*%t(U)
VV<-V-B%*%V[2:(nrow(V)),2:(ncol(V))]%*%t(B)
sum(abs(X-VV))
}
```

Comment: $X$ must also be symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tilde{{\bf B}} := \begin{bmatrix} {\bf B} & {\bf 0}_n \end{bmatrix}$. We have the following linear matrix equation in symmetric matrix $\bf V$

$$ {\bf V} - \tilde{{\bf B}} {\bf V} \tilde{{\bf B}}^\top = {\bf X} $$

which can be rewritten as a linear system using half-[vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))

$$ \left( {\bf I}_{n^2} - \left( \tilde{{\bf B}} \otimes \tilde{{\bf B}} \right) \right) {\bf D}_n \mbox{vech} ({\bf V}) = {\bf D}_n \mbox{vech} ({\bf X}) $$

where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and ${\bf D}_n$ is a [duplication matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices).

---

**Related**

- [Linear matrix equation $AXA^T=B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2276902/339790)
- [Solving linear matrix equations of the form $X = AXA^T + C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/348487/339790)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very impressive. What textbook do you recommend for learning this sort of knowledge?

Comment: @LLT Tom Minka, [Old and New Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/old-new-matrix-algebra-useful-statistics/), September 1997

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo hi, have we met at Symmetry? If so, nice to see you again